# Set Custom Components as children prop in React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am trying to create a custom `RadioGroup` that takes custom component: `Radio` as children prop

This is my code so far

```
/* RadioGroup Component */
export interface RadioGroupProps {
  value?: boolean;
  onChange?: (value: boolean) => void;
  size?: "sm" | "lg" | "md";
  radioStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export default function RadioGroup({ value, onChange, size = "md"}: RadioGroupProps) {
  return (
    <span className="radio-container">
    </span>
  );
}

/*Radio Child Component */ 

export interface RadioProps {
  value: string | number;
  label: string;
}
export function Radio({ value, label }: RadioProps) {
  return (
    <span className="radio-container">
      <span className="radio"></span>
    </span>
  );
}
```

I want to specify the only children `RadioGroup` can receive are `Radio` components so I can  use them like this:

```
<RadioGroup>
          <Radio label="Sarah" value={"Sarah"} />
          <Radio label="Abraham" value={"Abraham"} />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Try to create component using React.FC 
I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: What's the issue now?

Comment: @LinDu It can accept any component or element as children. I don't want RadioGroup to accept any children except Radio

Comment: try to iterate for children prop with React.Children.forEach and collect children which are radio elements in new children array. For example, extend default ExoticComponent type with optional id key and set Radio.id = 'radio'. When check at forEach child.type.id === 'id'. But be careful, child can be not only object